# How to call method on Button

Tags: android, android-button

Im have a problem with this. the error is , bitmap (String) in MainActivity cannot be applied

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           bitmap();
        }
    });

    private File bitmap(String filename) {
     (codes)...
    }
```

how can i solve this. im new in programming by the way

Comment: Could you post that method?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `setOnClickListener` method like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
   // your file path

       String path=":/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1414240995236.jpg";//it contain your path of image..im using a temp string..
String filename=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
       bitmap(filename);
    }
});
```